# Как лучше подключить векторные иконки для сайта?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, vector

Как лучше подключить иконки?

Через иконочный шрифт, svg спрайт, или сразу через код в формате BASE64?

и в чем разница между ними?

Comment: Так, как лучше подходит для вас, для вашего сайта и для ваших иконок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через SVG спрайт.

Во-первых, тогда вам будут доступны иконки как background-image -  в случае со шрифтом придется добавлять элементы или псевдоэлементы.

Во-вторых, на устройстве пользователя могут быть проигнорированы кастомные шрифты (многие пользователи специально включают такой режим, чтобы вместо мутного/тонкого/косого дизайнерского выпендрежа читать сайт с нормальным санс-серифом). С свг такого не будет.

В-третьих, с свг проще извращаться на предмет анимации и транзишенов.

Ну а код в base64 используется только в двух случаях: когда кроме как к css-ке нет доступа никуда и когда крайне важно сократить число запросов файлов с сервера.